# PowerShell's Sort-Object cmdlet changing the order w.r.t. attributes not sorted on

Tags: sorting, powershell

I'm sorting some XML and would like to sort elements based on a particular, *non-unique* attribute, which allows me to group like-elements.  Within these groups, I need to keep the original ordering.  The problem is that when sorting, the order inside these groups changes and when re-sorting then the order changes yet again.  I need a sort that doesn't change things if the content of the XML hasn't changed (otherwise SVN diffs are ugly).  Here is a simplified example:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<root>
  <element name="a" number="1" />
  <element name="b" number="1" />
  <element name="c" number="1" />
  <element name="d" number="2" />
  <element name="e" number="2" />
  <element name="f" number="2" />
  <element name="g" number="3" />
  <element name="h" number="3" />
</root>
"@

Write-Host "`nFirst Sort produces this:"
$result1 = $xml.SelectNodes('//element') | Sort-Object -Property 'number'
Write-Host (($result1 | select -ExpandProperty 'number') + " <---Sorted on")
Write-Host (($result1 | select -ExpandProperty 'name') + " <---Order not maintained")

Write-Host "`nSorting the (already sorted) results of First Sort produces this:"
$result2 = $result1 | Sort-Object -Property 'number'
Write-Host (($result2 | select -ExpandProperty 'number') + " <---Sorted on")
Write-Host (($result2 | select -ExpandProperty 'name') + " <---Order changed again")
```

Here is the output:

```
First Sort produces this:
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3  <---Sorted on
c b a f e d h g  <---Order not maintained

Sorting the (already sorted) results of First Sort produces this:
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3  <---Sorted on
a b c d e f g h  <---Order changed again
```

In this example, I need to preserve the original "name" ordering within the "number groups".

Can anyone think of an *easy* way to make this maintain the original order and come out the same when sorting multiple times?

I'm trying to avoid adding dummy attributes representing the original ordering.  Maybe there is a different .NET sorting function that's more deterministic?  I searched but nobody seemed to be concerned with ordering within equivalent groups.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but can you just sort on more properties?  E.g., "Sort-Object Number,Name"

Comment: Unfortunately no, those are the ones I need to preserve the original order of (the order of those has human meaning, these are source files people read/edit). Good question.

Comment: The documentation of `Sort-Object` doesn't state anywhere that it uses a stable sort, so no reason to expect it.

Comment: I never expected it to be a stable sort, Joey, and it's not, so I wrote this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have something that already represents the natural sort order, you can just add an index property with Add-Member:

```
$nodes = @($xml.SelectNodes('//element'))
for ($i=0; $i -lt $nodes.Count; $i++) 
{
    $nodes[$i] = $nodes[$i] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty "Index" $i -PassThru
}

$result1 = $nodes | Sort-Object name, Index
```

Then you are guaranteed to get the same ordering no matter how many times you re-sort.

Update: added syntax for PowerShell v2

Comment: I think that's probably the best I can do.  I was hoping not to add an attribute, but maybe there isn't a standard sorting mechanism that keeps the original ordering.  I'll give it a shot this week then mark the answer. :)

Comment: Hmm, I can't get Add-Member to work on type System.Xml.XmlElement.  It doesn't receive the new member.  The help article says Add-Member works on "an instance of a Windows PowerShell object", which I guess doesn't include arbitrary .NET objects?  I guess I'll have to use an XML attribute with a really obscure name.  It's a hack, but it should work.

Comment: Whoops, I only tested it with the PowerShell v3 preview!  Apparently v3 is a little more liberal with it's list processing.  You can add "@( )" around $xml.SelectNodes to interpret the result as a PowerShell list.

Comment: BTW: Add-Member will automatically wrap a .NET object with a PSObject that contains the NoteProperty

Comment: I'd probably use `$nodes | ForEach-Object { $i = 0 } { $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty Index $i; $i++ }`. Note also that you don't need to quote arguments to cmdlets unless you need special string processing.

Comment: JohnB: To get rid of the index afterwards you can just use `Select-Object` to filter the properties to return.

Comment: It appears that, at least in v2, I must use the assignment operator and the -passthru param, like this: `$nodes[$i] = $nodes[$i] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty "Index" $i -PassThru`.  That seems to do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: It worked fine for me (before your edits) on PowerShell v2.  I think your code must be different, specifically the list you are operating on.  But I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Sort with respect to both the properties:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//element') | Sort-Object -Property number, name
```

This produces this output:

```
name     number
----     ------
a        1
b        1
c        1
d        2
e        2
f        2
g        3
h        3
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to preserve the original order the name attribute, which might not be alphabetized as in the sample.